# How to get the final redirected URL when using reactive WebClient with followRedirect(true)

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

How do I get the final URL?
(The URL http://mz.cm/1gpgLAJ is redirected to https://moz.com/blog/announcing-mozcon-local-2016?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_content=announcing_mozcon_local_2016&utm_campaign=blog_post)

```
WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                        HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)
                )).build()
                .get()
                .uri("http://mz.cm/1gpgLAJ")
                .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                    ....
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for redirect event with `doOnRedirect`. See below your example extended with `doOnRedirect` callback. More information about lifecycle callbacks you can find [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_lifecycle_callbacks_4).

```
WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
                    HttpClient.create().followRedirect(true)
                        .doOnRedirect((res, conn) ->
                            System.out.println("Location header: " + res.responseHeaders().get("Location")))
            )).build()
            .get()
            .uri("http://mz.cm/1gpgLAJ")
            .exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {
                ....
            });
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the URL from ClientResponse?